# El Capitan OS X and Nxt v2

Tags: nxt

I am running El Capitan OS x, and I have a nxt v2 brick. Is there anyway I use them together?

The nxt installer crashes and the ev3 software will not update the firmware on the brick. Do I have any options?

Here is my stack trace (without the last 19k characters):

```
Process:               Install [1325]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/Install.app/Contents/MacOS/Install
Identifier:            Install
Version:               1.0.0.4 (1.0.0)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Install [1325]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-11-03 22:25:39.680 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        0F66AABE-5D5C-A509-9AC1-B9E99FC7DEB9

Sleep/Wake UUID:       86EFE853-0BEC-46BF-BE6B-02C638F5D22A

Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       46 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x999dcdf2 _vsnprintf + 57
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x999dd15c vsnprintf_l + 63
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x999cdf22 snprintf + 82
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x029272a4 void (anonymous namespace)::_ToDebugStream(DebugStream&, char const*, unsigned long const&) + 52
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0276f494 ToDebugStream(DebugStream&, unsigned long) + 40
5   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0217c54a EventOracle::DestroyQueueObject(unsigned long, long) + 112
6   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02172a08 EventNodeRTInit + 764
7   ???                             0x010c7e8a 0 + 17596042

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a38b2 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9a807792 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 234
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9a807366 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a2e16 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b35f _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08f82 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a2e16 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b35f _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08f82 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a2e16 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b35f _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08f82 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c24f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02286edf ThTmoEventWait + 339
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02249910 OccTimerThread(OccTimerThreadRec*) + 122
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a2e16 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b35f _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08f82 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a27fa __select_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9859f744 select + 94
2   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02247576 NetLoop(void*) + 208
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0d8c1 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x93f4d2a0 TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 167
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x93f4cdf9 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 499
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x93f4cff2 TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x93f3177d TimerThread + 93
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9859c19a mach_wait_until + 10
1   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x93f235bf MPDelayUntil + 26
2   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0228cdc8 WSleep + 52
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x021dba95 CountDownThread(long) + 101
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a2e16 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b35f _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08f82 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c24f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278589e PlatformEventPosix::WaitCore(long) + 42
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02785b1b PlatformEventPosix::Wait(long) + 77
5   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278709b ThEventWait + 113
6   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215e5ed DeqPrEQ + 519
7   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215fa23 Exec + 149
8   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02155d85 ExecWrapper(void*) + 179
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c24f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278589e PlatformEventPosix::WaitCore(long) + 42
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02785b1b PlatformEventPosix::Wait(long) + 77
5   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278709b ThEventWait + 113
6   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215e5ed DeqPrEQ + 519
7   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215fa23 Exec + 149
8   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02155d85 ExecWrapper(void*) + 179
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c24f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278589e PlatformEventPosix::WaitCore(long) + 42
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02785b1b PlatformEventPosix::Wait(long) + 77
5   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278709b ThEventWait + 113
6   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215e5ed DeqPrEQ + 519
7   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215fa23 Exec + 149
8   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02155d85 ExecWrapper(void*) + 179
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x985a24a2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c5b8 _pthread_cond_wait + 868
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0c24f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278589e PlatformEventPosix::WaitCore(long) + 42
4   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02785b1b PlatformEventPosix::Wait(long) + 77
5   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0278709b ThEventWait + 113
6   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215e5ed DeqPrEQ + 519
7   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x0215fa23 Exec + 149
8   com.ni.labviewRuntime           0x02155d85 ExecWrapper(void*) + 179
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b794 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f0b70a _pthread_start + 155
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91f08fa6 thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xbfffb3cc  ebx: 0x00000100  ecx: 0x00000100  edx: 0xa3e205f8
  edi: 0x00000100  esi: 0xa3e20038  ebp: 0xbfffb494  esp: 0xbfffb31c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010292  eip: 0x999dcdf2   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x0296b6ec

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13


Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x76db +Install (1.0.0.4 - 1.0.0) /Volumes/VOLUME/Install.app/Contents/MacOS/Install
 0x2000000 -  0x2b8bfff +com.ni.labviewRuntime (8.2.1 - 8.2) /Volumes/VOLUME/Install.app/Support/LabVIEW 8.2 Runtime.framework/LabVIEW 8.2 Runtime
 0x37a1000 -  0x37a1ffc +com.ni.labview.bundleBroker (1.0) /Volumes/VOLUME/Install.app/Support/LabVIEW 8.2 Runtime.framework/Support/LabVIEWBundleBroker.bundle/Contents/MacOS/LabVIEWBundleBroker
 0x7508000 -  0x7595fff +com.ni.lvmesa (1.0) /Volumes/VOLUME/Install.app/Support/LabVIEW 8.2 Runtime.framework/Support/LVMesa.framework/LVMesa
 0xabf4000 -  0xabf4ffd +cl_kernels (???)  cl_kernels
0x8fe1c000 - 0x8fe505bf  dyld (360.17)  /usr/lib/dyld
0x90010000 - 0x900a4ff3  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
0x900a5000 - 0x900affff  libsystem_notify.dylib (149)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x901ad000 - 0x901b6fff  libcopyfile.dylib (127)  /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x9021c000 - 0x90220ffb  libGIF.dylib (1440)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x90c15000 - 0x90c1dffb  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (624.10.1)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x90c1e000 - 0x90c3dfff  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (2.0 - 239)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
0x90e73000 - 0x90f71fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (728.4 - 728.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x90f72000 - 0x90ff0ff3  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1178.10.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x90ff1000 - 0x91040fff  com.apple.opencl (2.6.9 - 2.6.9)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x91041000 - 0x91043fff  libquarantine.dylib (80)  /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x919e6000 - 0x919e6fff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (169)  /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
0x919e7000 - 0x919e9fff  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (19)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x919ea000 - 0x91a07ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (34)  /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x91a08000 - 0x91a6bfff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x91a6c000 - 0x91b5dff3  libiconv.2.dylib (44)  /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x91d52000 - 0x91d53fff  liblangid.dylib (122)  /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x91d5c000 - 0x91d5cfff  com.apple.Carbon (154 - 157)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x91d5e000 - 0x91db7ff7  com.apple.AE (701 - 701)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x91db8000 - 0x91dc6ff3  com.apple.opengl (12.0.34 - 12.0.34)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x91dc7000 - 0x91e04ff7  com.apple.DebugSymbols (132 - 132)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
0x91e05000 - 0x91e12ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.4.12 - 5.4.12)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x91e13000 - 0x91e89ff3  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55126)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x91ef4000 - 0x91f07ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib (209)  /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x91f08000 - 0x91f10ffb  libsystem_pthread.dylib (137.1.1)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x91f11000 - 0x91f14ff7  com.apple.help (1.3.3 - 46)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x91f15000 - 0x91f19fff  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.6 - 96)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x91f1a000 - 0x91f27ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (38)  /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x91f28000 - 0x91fa2ff7  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
0x91fa3000 - 0x92006fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (728.4 - 728.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x92049000 - 0x92071ffb  libxpc.dylib (755.1.19)  /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x92072000 - 0x920b2fff  com.apple.AppleJPEG (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/Versions/A/AppleJPEG
0x92257000 - 0x92260ffb  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
0x92268000 - 0x92270fff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1222.1.1 - 1222.1.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
0x92283000 - 0x92373ffb  com.apple.DiskImagesFramework (10.11.1 - 415)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Versions/A/DiskImages
0x92374000 - 0x928a2fdf  com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x928a3000 - 0x92a84fff  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11 - 410.9)  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x92a85000 - 0x92a88ffb  libutil.dylib (43)  /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
0x92a89000 - 0x92c02ff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.13 - 1.13)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x92c05000 - 0x92c0dfff  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.3 - 1.3)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
0x92c0e000 - 0x92c22ff7  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
0x92c58000 - 0x92c64ff7  libkxld.dylib (3247.10.11)  /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x92c65000 - 0x92c9ffff  com.apple.MediaKit (16 - 807)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/Versions/A/MediaKit
0x92ca0000 - 0x92cfbfff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (11.0 - 472)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x92cfc000 - 0x92d3dff7  libauto.dylib (186)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x92d3e000 - 0x92fe1fff  libmecabra.dylib (696.1)  /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x93081000 - 0x930d5ffb  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x930d6000 - 0x93149ffb  com.apple.datadetectorscore (7.0 - 460)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
0x9314a000 - 0x9314afff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.13 - 1.13)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x9314b000 - 0x934a630b  libobjc.A.dylib (680)  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x934a7000 - 0x9367aff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1440)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x9367b000 - 0x9367cfff  libSystem.B.dylib (1225.1.1)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x9367d000 - 0x93781fff  libJP2.dylib (1440)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
0x937ce000 - 0x937dafff  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.11 - 716)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
0x937db000 - 0x9382afff  libcurl.4.dylib (90)  /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
0x9382b000 - 0x93881ff7  libc++.1.dylib (120.1)  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x93df3000 - 0x93e91ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x93e92000 - 0x9418dfff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1136 - 1136)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x9418e000 - 0x94192fff  libheimdal-asn1.dylib (452.1.1)  /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
0x94658000 - 0x94658fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9465d000 - 0x946b4ff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 548)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x946b5000 - 0x946c8ff7  libcmph.dylib (6)  /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x946c9000 - 0x946cafff  libremovefile.dylib (41)  /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x946cb000 - 0x946cfffb  com.apple.IOSurface (108.0.1 - 108.0.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x946d0000 - 0x94b63fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1255.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x94b64000 - 0x94ba0fff  com.apple.RemoteViewServices (2.0 - 99)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteViewServices.framework/Versions/A/RemoteViewServices
0x94ba1000 - 0x94ba6ff7  libmacho.dylib (875.1)  /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x94ba7000 - 0x94bb2ff3  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60074)  /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x94bb3000 - 0x94bb8fff  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
0x94bb9000 - 0x94bc2ff3  com.apple.AppleSRP (5.0 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/Versions/A/AppleSRP
0x94bc3000 - 0x94bcefff  com.apple.NetAuth (6.0 - 6.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
0x94e4e000 - 0x94e88fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5)  /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x95757000 - 0x9577affb  com.apple.framework.Apple80211 (11.0 - 1102.32)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211
0x95b37000 - 0x95b76ffb  libGLImage.dylib (12.0.34.12)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x95b77000 - 0x95b8dfe7  libcompression.dylib (23)  /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x95b8e000 - 0x95b91fff  libScreenReader.dylib (425.100)  /usr/lib/libScreenReader.dylib
0x95b92000 - 0x95c81ff7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (59)  /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x95c82000 - 0x95c89fff  com.apple.agl (3.3.1 - AGL-3.3.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL
0x95c8a000 - 0x95c99ff7  libxar.1.dylib (302)  /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
0x95f99000 - 0x9611effb  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 435)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
0x9611f000 - 0x96147ff7  com.apple.IconServices (68 - 68)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/Versions/A/IconServices
0x96148000 - 0x96166ffb  libresolv.9.dylib (60)  /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x96167000 - 0x96180fff  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1)
```

Comment: Can you post information about the crash (usually can be found in Console.app)? I installed NXT 2.0 software recently on a new MacBook, but I think it was before I upgraded to El Capitan. The installer supposedly doesn't work on Yosemite either, but it worked for me, so maybe there is hope for El Capitan as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to install Windows on your Mac, either in a virtual machine or as dual boot, then install the NXT 2.0 software in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I had that error when trying to install the NXT 2 installer (after having previously uninstalled Flash, to be sure).  What I did was to not run the main installer, but instead the language specific installer (in my case English ... .mpkg, if I am not mistaken).

I am not sure if I just used a different download for EV3 or if I just automatically skipped the main installer, but I did not have that error for that version.

[image: contents of .iso file in Finder]

Comment: Nice workaround. I confirmed that I was able to (re)install using the v2.0f4 .iso file from https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service using .mpkg file rather than the .app file on OS X 10.11.2.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to install each parts manually:

-go to th 'Parts' Folder in MINDSTORMS NXT (^^^^^)

-Uninstall Flash Player if you don't have Flash Player 10

-Install Flash Player 10 from the 'PARTS' folder

-Install the packages in the language you prefer

-Install the packages that have no specified language

-Go to launchpad and click MINDSTORMS NXT

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: **WARNING:** Doing this can lead to serious security vulnerabilities in any other software using the system installed Flash Player, like internet browsers.